# Will the ArrayList be published safely after putting into j.u.c.ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I have some doubd with ArrayList safe publication.

I have code:

```
private final Map<Long, SomeStuff> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
//Called by Thread 1
public void write() {
   List list = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int i = 0; i <100 ; i++) {
      list.add(new SomeStuff(i))
   }
   map.put(1L,list)
}
// Called by Thread 2
public void read() {
   List list = map.get(1L);
}
```

Will the  ivocation of map.get(1L) return ArrayList in correct state(has correct size for example)?

What about elements of ArrayList? Will the elements  be published safely?

I noticed that `ConcurrentHashMap.put` guarded by lock on Node,that will be modified, but `ConcurrentHashMap.get` performs throught `Unsafe.getObjectVolatile`.

And i think that ArrayList might be published unsafety

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: yes, the ArrayList object will be published safely along with its elements.

You shouldn't generally look into the class's source code and make any conclusions about thread safety yourself, but you should rather rely on guarantees that are given in a class/interface javadoc. I strongly recommend the book "Java Concurrency in Practice" that elaborates on such approaches.

The ConcurrentMap (which is implemented by ConcurrentHashMap) interface states:

> Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a ConcurrentMap as a key or value happen-before actions subsequent to the access or removal of that object from the ConcurrentMap in another thread.

which means that anything that happened before the "put" is visible to the thread that makes a "get" on the same object afterwards. Which means that in the case the "get" happens after the "put" then your second thread will see a "good" ArrayList object with all its elements.

And here is a note that is not about safe publication, but just a thing to remember:

ArrayList itself (and possibly your elements' class) is not thread-safe. But you can be OK with it as long as you don't modify those objects from some other threads. As described in the "Java Concurrency in Practice" book - this is "Serial Thread Confinement" which means that you can safely publish a non-thread-safe object from one thread to another thread thus transferring "ownership" from a thread to a thread and thus making the object "Thread Confined" at a particular point in time. As I said it applies only if you make sure it is not modified from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Ruslan.

Answer (score 1):

**ConcurrentHashMap will be thread safe, but not ArrayList**

means if the reader calls `get` before writer's `put` call, then result will be `null`. If the writer calls put before reader's `get` call, then result will be the `List object`

So if you add the items to the list (code below)

```
for (int i = 0; i <100 ; i++) {
   list.add(new SomeStuff(i))
}
```

before the `put` it will be OK because the List will not be accessable from reader

but if after the `put` it will be accessable from reader and cause reader and writer to read or write to the ArrayList concurrently. This might cause problems because ArrayList not thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @sungjin-steve-yoo 
What about memory visibility? Will the CPU  cashes be flushed after write?

Comment: @user3356477 see this article for much more detail about ConcurrentHashMap https://www.burnison.ca/articles/the-concurrency-of-concurrenthashmap

Comment: @user3356477 about visibility - see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059031/will-the-arraylist-be-published-safely-after-putting-into-j-u-c-concurrenthashma/45170119#45170119